# http request loop not sending

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

Why does this not send a http request? i'm trying to add all friends from the person logged in into the mysql table. When i use this url manually in my browser http://www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_friends.php?name=%@&id=%@&userid=%@

it add the values %@, but not when i run the objective-c code. What am i doing wrong with the http request loop?

```
for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {

     NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_friends.php?name=%@&id=%@&userid=%@",friend.name, friend.id, currentId];

     // to execute php code
     NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    // to receive the returend value
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
}
```

Comment: do `NSLog(@"%@", strURL)` and check/post the result

Comment: it posts all the url example: www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_friends.php?name=Christian Pedersen&id=100007624599560&userid=1386243223

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more clear what are you trying to accomplish here.. the Url that nslog prints out looks fine.. what do you mean by adding %@? all you did in this look is creating again and again -one- string of URL and didn't do anything with it...

Comment: What i mean is if i put this in my browser http://www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_friends.php?name=%@&id=%@&userid=%@

it will add %@ %@ %@ to my table in a row. This indicate that the php script is working. So when its not adding anything to the table when i run the App, indicate that the http request are not working correctly.